# Angular 5 Dynamic sidebar routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I helping on a project to build a dashboard for my company.

The our dashboard will have a sidenav, the content of this sidenav will change based on which portion of the application you are in.

Below are some mockups of the intent.

When a User navigates to the settings portion the sidebar would update to links that are important in settings so in this example the URL would be.

example.com/dashboard/settings/profile and if the user navigated to say calendar it would change to .../settings/calendar

[image]

We do have one page that is a somewhat special case however. Our CRM page has a relatively simple sidebar with only 2 links (e.g. .../crm/contacts/list) but once you load the details of a either a client contact or company additional links would be appended to the existing list. (e.g. .../crm/contacts/detail/5)

[image]

This secondary info would also be rendered in the bottom half of a client contact/company details. (e.g. .../crm/contacts/detail/5/addresses)

[image]

I'm looking for suggestions on how to tackle this, and to take it from there.
Would it be better to use 1 component, with the links for the various sidenavs in their own components and loaded based on some switchCase?

Or to use named router outlets to dynamically load the sidenav in?

or any other suggestions.

Comment: What did you do in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can create angular service for your application that controls structure with menu-items provided by various cases. So you can dispatch it based on every application part needs.